# Importing a Hbase snapshot from HDFS

Tags: hbase, hdfs, backup-strategies

I have created a snapshot of a table in Hbase and exported it using 
    hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot  -copy-to 
Now I have deleted the snapshot from Hbase. How can I import the snapshot from HDFS back to Hbase.

Comment: bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import <tablename> <inputdir>

Comment: I don't have that table anymore in hbase. I have the table metadata information in the snapshot. I want to backup the deleted table with that snapshot

Answer (score 1):

hadoop fs -put hdfs:///pathNameWhereSnapshotWasPutInitially /hbase/data/default/tablename/cde4801e4c115003ef51e50f5ef23041/1/

where cde4801e4c115003ef51e50f5ef23041 is subjected to change.